# Passing Parameters is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to delete a user from Default Membership of MVC but the passing parameters is always null. I've used `[HttpDelete]` attribute and `[FromBody]` but it gives *"500 Server internal error"*. below is my code

```
    // Delete api/Del/user name

    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteUser(string user)
    {

        try
        {
            System.Web.Security.Membership.DeleteUser(user);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }


        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

This is my calling method with "Delete" verb.

```
http://localhost:3325/api/Del/haris2
```

I've created this webapi class for routing. I have a Get Method in Same controller with no arguments. Its working is fine.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DatabaseService_WebAPI.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Filters
            config.Filters.Add(new QueryableAttribute());


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiwithAction",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be an issue with your routing, can you provide your route configuration?

Comment: You definitely need the `[HttpDelete]` attribute at the top of your `Delete` method (not sure why adding that would be throwing a server error). Are you actually posting using `DELETE` as the verb?

Comment: Those 2 routes are essentially the same (ie, how will the routing mechanism determine if `haris2` is an id or an action?) And I'm presuming the `DeleteUser` action is in the `DelController` controller?

Comment: now i used [HttpDelete] but the parameter is null. i`m using Rest Client Debugger for firefox.

Comment: yes, Delete user is a action in DelController. Now i comment my "DefaultApiwithAction" route. but the value is null :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is MVC maps your parameters **by name**. So there are two ways to fix your problem

1. Change the name of your action parameter to `id` as that's what your mapped path expects e.g.

   ```
   public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Update your route to look for a `user` parameter instead of an id e.g.

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}",
       defaults: new { user = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
   ```